# Как избавиться от большого количества компонентов на игровом объекте игрок?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня на сцене есть объект игрок и на нем куча компонентов (здоровье, инвентарь, контроллер, колайдер и тд). И мне допустим необходимо узнать количество здоровья или направление движения. Для этого, мне придётся брать объект и через getcomponent брать необходимый компонент. Как лучше от этого избавиться?
Я думал о создании класса плеерФасад и в нем хранить все ссылки на компоненты и имя игрока, но это не подходит, потому что при создании новых компонентов для игрока  мне придётся изменять скрипт плеер, а так же все равно не решает проблему хранения огромного количества монобехов на сцене.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно перестать пользоваться монобехами без повода и писать обычные `C#` классы. Дробить ответственности на маленькие класы дело хорошее, но из этого еще нужно выстраивать архитектуру. Класса `Player` в таких играх существовать не должно, поскольку он не отличается от остальных акторов сцены, фигня, которая бегает, атакует и может сдохнуть.

Этот фасад безусловно нужен, но должен он быть модульным. И это не фасад вовсе, это `UnitModel` которая, как обладатель интерфейса `IDamagable` должен получать урон и будучи юнитом обрабатывать его через здровье, а какая нибудь бочка не имеет здоровья, разбивается просто по факту нанесения урона. Наличие инвентаря есть у `HeroUnitModel`, который наследник. У каждого юнита есть скин и коллайдер по логике часть его, а не модели, поскольку зависит от габаритов визуала. Помимо здоровья, маны, стамины и скина может содержать еще много опций, типа фракции `player`, `enemy`, `neutral`...

Косаемо других модулей, это просто набор самостоятельных функций типа движения, атаки, выбор таргета, у скина тоже может быть свои модули с особыми функциями. Модули могут быть просто монобехами висящими на дочерних объектах и их может быть разный набор, например у турели нет модуля хотьбы. Моделе ваще пофиг, на то что делают модули, у неё просто их массив, поскольку они все наследники `UnitModul` и всё, работают они автономно, реагируя на то что происходит с моделью.

Контроллеры вообще должны быть вне модели, им должно быть пофиг каким юнитом управлять, что `PlayerController`, что `EnemyAIController`, какой `SetTargetUnit()` задашь, тем и управляют. Камера и вся визуализаця `UI`, как тот-же таргет так-же часть `PlayerController` и некоим образом не галавняк модели. Любая нормальная рпг написана так, что ты можешь поменять скин персонажа игрока на любой в игре и она работает, более того, можно указать любого юнита как цель управления и играть хоть скелетом первого уровня, хоть боссом, все в руках разработчика, поскольку архитектура гибкая, нет цемента.

РПГ вообще хорошо писать сложно, нужно много навыка.

Comment: Получается если мне нужно в PlayerController указать направление движения для charecterMovement, то мне при инициализации контролера нужно закешировать из массива UnitModul[ ], который находиться в  UnitModel, нужный мне charecterMovement и указать ему направление? или направление движения реализуется в HeroUnitModel?

Comment: Есть такие свойства, которые одни сущьности задают, другие их используют, пользователей может быть несколько, а может и вообще не быть. Вектор движения показателен, указывается контроллером, игроком или ai, а использовать могут модули движения, поворота, выбора цели и т.д, а может и никто, но не будет же котроллер это проверять. Поэтому создать какую нибудь структуру с подобными свойствами, как посредника, прямые связи потом больно аукаются. Поиск в списке модуля и обращение к нему лучше избегать, максимум проверка на наличие.